# Dynamically load JSON on click and populate list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have several JSON files and I'd like to load them on the fly using the javascript click event and populate an unordered list. How can I do that? My solution isn't working. Should I be using a javascript framework like AngularJS for this?

Here's my code:

```
<!-- start home -->
<span data-deck="home" class="load-map home-marker marker current-level node" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
</span><!-- end home -->

<!-- start housing -->
<span data-deck="housing" class="load-map housing-marker marker current-level node" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
</span><!-- end housing -->

<!-- start school -->
<span data-deck="school" class="load-map school-marker marker node" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
</span><!-- end school -->
```

JS

```
$('.load-map').click(function()
{
    var deck = $(this).attr('data-deck');
    $('.load-map').removeClass('current-level');
    $(this).addClass('current-level');
    alert(deck)

        $.ajax({ 
          type : 'GET', 
          url : 'data/' + deck + '.json', 
          async : true, 
          dataType : 'JSON', 
          success : function(result){
           var buffer="";
            $.each(result, function(index, val){ 
              for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++){ 
                var item = val[i]; 
                console.log(item.FlavourText);
                buffer+="<li data-type='"+item.type+"' data-tier='"+item.tier+"' class='stack__item'></li>";

              } 
              $('#card-data ul').html(buffer);
            });
          }
         });

    });
```

JSON EXAMPLE

```
[
  {
    "Card #": 0,
    "Type": "Opportunity",
    "Tier": 1
  },
  {
    "Card #": 5,
    "Type": "Opportunity",
    "Tier": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Why `async: false`? Why `jsonp`? Why empty `beforeSend` function? What does `My solution isn't working` mean? And no, you don't need a framework  (Angular or anything else) for this

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I've edited the code to remove what's unnecessary. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not easy to understand from your code, but I see you have wrapped the ajax inside another jquery object, which may be unnecessary.

```
  $('.load-map').click(function() {
  var deck = $(this).attr('data-deck');
  $('.load-map').removeClass('current-level');
  $(this).addClass('current-level');
  alert(deck)

    $.ajax({
      // rest of the code
    });

});
```

Also there is an empty `setTimeout` inside this click handler,